# remove/toggle class when users clicks on the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 3 or so button in my page which i need to show a social icon when user clicks on those links.
I used this jQuery

```
$('.one').on('click', function() {
  $('.smenu').not($(this).next()).removeClass('share')
  $(this).next().toggleClass('share');
});


<div id="sharing_area">
  <ul class='smenu'>
    <li class="facebook"><a target="_blank" onclick="return windowpop(this.href, 545, 433)" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://youtu.be/<? echo $id_3 ?>"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
    <span class="one">Share</span>
</div>
```

I keep getting error, but i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
Can you guys help me out?

Here is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5dsrk470/1/)

Comment: He's not using IDs in this code.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Barmar, he is using duplicate id's in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @Barmar he is in the fiddle

Comment: There is no `.next()` element for the span you are clicking!

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, but it might be better to use IDs. For example, have the `<li class="smenu" id="smenu1">` (where the id is "smenu" + number) and get the number from the id, add one to that and use jQuery to reference it.

Comment: you use of next() is not going to work and the not() is not going to work. The logic is flawed, hence why it does not work.

Comment: Please put the HTML into your question. The problem is that your jQuery code doesn't match the HTML structure, and the question doesn't demonstrate that with just the jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no .next() element for the span you are clicking! Your UL is before the span, so you need `prev()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5dsrk470/5/

```
$('.one').on('click', function() {
    console.log('click');
  $('.smenu').not($(this).prev()).removeClass('share')
  $(this).prev().toggleClass('share');
});
```

If you want to remove the class on clicking the links add this delegated event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    $('.smenu').removeClass('share')
});
```

Comment: @user3067592: Added the bit to handler the links, but `windowPop` is not defined in the JSFiddle, so the example will not work there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you confused prev and next methods:

```
var $smenu = $('.smenu');
$('.one').on('click', function () {
    $smenu.removeClass('share');
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('share');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5dsrk470/6/